# GNOME Shell's application menu is zoomed out on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell

Under the Applications Menu in GNOME, everything seems to be zoomed out(pictures below). Just installed today, haven't done too much.

Only installed extensions are Dynamic Panel Transparency(enabled), Desktop Icons(disabled), Ubuntu AppIndicators(enabled), and Ubuntu Dock(enabled). Dash to dock was installed for a brief period, but has since been removed.

[image: image 1]

Along with this, it exits the zoomed-in state if I open an app folder:

[image: image 2]

Update: Disabling all extensions and rebooting still doesn't fix the issues.

---

Processor: Intel® Celeron(R) N4000 CPU @ 1.10GHz × 2

Graphics: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 600 (GLK 2)

Comment: What happens if you place the dock at the left side instead of bottom and reboot?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I just did a fresh Ubuntu install with no added extensions or anything, even putting it on the left and rebooting results in the same graphical "glitches". I do have my icon size at 36, as well as using a custom icon pack, theme, and cursor, but that shouldn't be related, right?